# Image into js Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, image, iframe

I have a iframe set up in js...the iframe loads a url that displays , can I add a logo image on top of that iframe so that hte page content of iframe is in the back and my logo on top of that iframe?

code :

```
var filePath = 'https://blablabla.com';
var iframe='<iframe id="frame" name="widget" src ="#" width="100%" height="1" margin=auto frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
document.write(iframe);
var myIframe = parent.document.getElementById("frame");
myIframe.height = 1280;
myIframe.width = 1024;
myIframe.src = filePath;
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need a positioned wrapper for the `iframe`, then position and size the image in the wrapper.

Comment: Hmm... maybe my edition was too hard, the code after `document.write()` is supposed to execute from the `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use CSS absolute positioning for this?

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/MPPqV/

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}

That works 100% thanks guys BUT....that positions it in top left corner...need it to go a bit more to the right , how to do?

Comment: `left: 20px;` to move it 20px from the left.